# Java: How to ask the user if he/she wants to play again

Tags: java, loops, do-while

How do you ask the user if he/she wants to play again.
 I have to ask the user to enter a char for this – ‘y’ or ‘n’ (Making sure this is not case sensitive)

if the user inputs 'y', then I want it to loop the question "How many rounds would you like to play" and then the "[block of code]".

```
    //asks user for their name
    System.out.println("\nWhat is your name?");
    name = in.nextLine();

    //asks user the number of rounds they want to play
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
    numRound = in.nextInt();

    char cont = 'y';

    do {
          [block of code ]
        }

    } while (roundnum <= numRound);     
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
    cont = in.next().charAt(0);
    while (cont == 'y');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using a while loop to check for whether the user wants to play again, but you're starting the loop at the wrong place. Your while loop should begin just before any actions you want repeated. So the pseudocode would be roughly:

```
while (cont == 'y'){
    //Enter game code here
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
    cont = in.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Also, *never* end a conditional with a semicolon. It won't compile.

Comment: It will compile, and thats the scary part about it. Since it will just interpret the remaining block as standard block without `if` or `while` attached. I.e. `if (...); { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
play()

while(1) {
    System.out.println("Wanna play again? (y/N): ")
    choice = in.nextChar();

switch(choice) {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        play();
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N:
        System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Try again");
}

}


void play() {
    //asks user the number of rounds they want to play
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
    numRound = in.nextInt();

    char cont = 'y';

    do {
          [block of code ]
        }

    } while (roundnum <= numRound);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! is there a way to loop the game again without using switch case, only with while loops or do-while loops?